# Running a test multiple times in Robolectric

Tags: android, testing, junit, robolectric, test-runner

I want to run a test multiple times. For example, lets say I have a test class like this :-

```
RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class Common {
     int n = 0;
     @Test
     public void shouldRun() {
          System.out.println(n++);
     ...
     }
}
```

Now, how can I keep repeating the test until a condition is met, like suppose if n = 10 then stop.

I tried a way as described in [this blog](http://codehowtos.blogspot.in/2011/04/run-junit-test-repeatedly.html), and created a custom test runner that extends RobolectricTestRunner and wrote the test class like this :-

```
@RunWith(ExtendedRobolectricTestRunner.class)
public abstract class Common  {    

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)  
    @Target({ElementType.METHOD})  
    public @interface Repeat {  
          int value();  
    }  

    int n = 0;

    @Test
    @Repeat(10)     
    public void shouldRunCase1Port() {      
        System.out.println(n++);
}
```

but didn't succeed.
Can anybody advice on it ?